# UITableView: How to display more then one detail cell and own custom button

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

For instance
[Course Name (cell title)
[Value: 30% (cell.detailTextLabel)                [my own custom button here as selector]
[Due: April, 2,2010](How can i add this)

Comment: Yes, a table can display more than one cell. Yes, you can have a button in a cell. What exactly is your question? Please rephrase.

Comment: I want to know how I can insert the "Due:..." to my current table row
right now I can only insert two which is cell.title and cell.detail

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous resources for creating custom UITableViewCell instances, both programmatically and with IB. [Here is one.](http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder)